# Count number of values which are less than current value

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to count the rows in the column *input* if the values are smaller than the current row (Please see the results wanted below). The issue to me is that the condition is based on current row value, so it is very different from general case where the condition is a fixed number.

```
data <- data.frame(input = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,5,5,5,5,6))

    input
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      1
5      2
6      2
7      3
8      5
9      5
10     5
11     5
12     6
```

The results I expect to get are like this. For example, for observations 5 and 6 (with value 2), there are 4 observations with value 1 less than their value 2. Hence *count* is given value 4.

```
    input count
1      1     0
2      1     0
3      1     0
4      1     0
5      2     4
6      2     4
7      3     6
8      5     7
9      5     7
10     5     7
11     5     7
12     6    11
```

---

Edit: as I am dealing with grouped data with `dplyr`, the ultimate results I wish to get is like below, that is, I am wishing the conditions could be dynamic within each group.

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4), 
input = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,5,5,5,5,6), 
count=c(0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,4))

   id input count
1   1     1     0
2   1     1     0
3   2     1     0
4   2     1     0
5   2     2     2
6   3     2     0
7   3     3     1
8   4     5     0
9   4     5     0
10  4     5     0
11  4     5     0
12  4     6     4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
   mutate(count = map_int(input, ~ sum(.x > input))) 
#    input count
#1      1     0
#2      1     0
#3      1     0
#4      1     0
#5      2     4
#6      2     4
#7      3     6
#8      5     7
#9      5     7
#10     5     7
#11     5     7
#12     6    11
```

#### Update

With the updated data, add the group by 'id' in the above code

```
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(count1 = map_int(input, ~ sum(.x > input)))
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   id [4]
#      id input count count1
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
# 1     1     1     0      0
# 2     1     1     0      0
# 3     2     1     0      0
# 4     2     1     0      0
# 5     2     2     2      2
# 6     3     2     0      0
# 7     3     3     1      1
# 8     4     5     0      0
# 9     4     5     0      0
#10     4     5     0      0
#11     4     5     0      0
#12     4     6     4      4
```

Answer (score 4):

In base R, we can use `sapply` and for each `input` count how many values are greater than itself.

```
data$count <- sapply(data$input, function(x) sum(x > data$input))

data

#   input count
#1      1     0
#2      1     0
#3      1     0
#4      1     0
#5      2     4
#6      2     4
#7      3     6
#8      5     7
#9      5     7
#10     5     7
#11     5     7
#12     6    11
```

---

With `dplyr` one way would be using `rowwise` function and following the same logic.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(count = sum(input > data$input))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Since I am dealing with group data using dplyr, and the example dataset I presented as is one of the group in my actual dataset, I am just wondering if there is way using dplyr (e.g. using mutate). Thanks!

Comment: @RickXMan I have shown a way using `mutate` in the answer for your example.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah . I tried to add `group_by` before it, but it seems `rowwise` is not compatible with `group_by`?

Answer (score 4):

**1**. `outer` and `rowSums`

```
data$count <- with(data, rowSums(outer(input, input, `>`)))
```

---

**2**. `table` and `cumsum`

```
tt <- cumsum(table(data$input))
v <- setNames(c(0, head(tt, -1)), c(head(names(tt), -1), tail(names(tt), 1)))
data$count <- v[match(data$input, names(v))]
```

---

**3**. `data.table` non-equi join

Perhaps more efficient with a non-equi join in `data.table`. Count number of rows (`.N`) for each match (`by = .EACHI`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[data, on = .(input < input), .N, by = .EACHI]
```

---

If your data is grouped by 'id', as in your update, join on that variable as well:

```
data[data, on = .(id, input < input), .N, by = .EACHI]

#     id input N
#  1:  1     1 0
#  2:  1     1 0
#  3:  2     1 0
#  4:  2     1 0
#  5:  2     2 2
#  6:  3     2 0
#  7:  3     3 1
#  8:  4     5 0
#  9:  4     5 0
# 10:  4     5 0
# 11:  4     5 0
# 12:  4     6 4
```