# Summed count with continuous scale

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where each observation has a continuous variable and a category variable.

I would like to create a plot where one axis is the continuous variable and the other shows how many times a certain category value occured.

eg. assume this is my dataframe:

| Observations | Continuous | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| obs1 | 20 | A |
| obs2 | 10 | B |
| obs3 | 15 | B |
| obs4 | 10 | A |
| obs5 | 12 | A |
| obs6 | 14 | A |

I would like to see how the number of summed observations falling into category A increase as the continuous variable goes from 0 to higher values.

```
    Observations <- c('obs1','obs2','obs3','obs4','obs5','obs6')
    Continuous <- c(20,10,15,10,12,14)
    Category <- c('A','B','B','A','A','A')
    df <- data.frame(Observations, Continuous, Category)
```

- x axis should be df$Continuous
- y axis should be the number of observations having df$Category == A and having df$Continuous <= x

Comment: Do you have a larger data set in reality? Could you explain how you sum the observations? Also to make it easier to use your data please paste the output of your dataframe into the question using `dput(your_dataframe)`

Comment: `ggplot` density plot?

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Unfortunatelly I do not have a larger dataset that I can share, but here is the example dataframe that I use:
Observations <- c('obs1','obs2','obs3','obs4','obs5','obs6')
Continuous <- c(20,10,15,10,12,14)
Category <- c('A','B','B','A','A','A')
df <- data.frame(Observations, Continuous, Category)

Also: x axis should be df$Continuous, y axis should be the number of observations having df$Category == A and having df$Continuous <= x

Comment: Also, you are missing a `c` in your assignment to `Observations`, it doesn't work as `(...)`, it needs to be `c(...)`. It helps when the code we're using is code you've used on your console, please.

Comment: Something close: [`ggplot2::stat_ecdf`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_ecdf.html), which plots the empirical cumulative distribution function; it plots proportions instead of counts, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a solution to use the tidyverse and ggplot:

```
library(tidyverse)
df_count <- df %>% 
  group_by(Category) %>%
  mutate(count = map_int(Continuous, ~sum(.x >= Continuous)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_count) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=Continuous, y= count)) + 
  facet_grid( .~Category)
```

[image]

(I found parts of the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53449830/count-number-of-values-which-are-less-than-current-value))